# Уровень C# для Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

На каком уровне знаний C# нужно программировать для написания хотя бы простеньких игр на Unity(более интересует 2D)?

Comment: Не попробуете - не узнаете. Мануалов по юнити полно, берите и пробуйте.

Comment: Подозреваю, что нужен синтаксис C#, все остальное уже Unity

Comment: Могли бы посоветовать литературу для изучения базы и синтакса C#?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/198316

Comment: а еще кроме cpu есть gpu, чтобы писать код для видеокарты пригодится не только шарп

Comment: В большинстве вы будете изучать сам Unity, по языку я бы сказал средние знания, половина объема книги троелсона или шилдта. Правда языком одним дело может не закончится: информатика, физика, математика и логика тоже пригодятся на базовом уровне.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ разве писать код напрямую для GPU имеет смысл, если используется готовый движок? Имхо, это полезно при разработке движка с 0, а если писать на готовом, то потребность в этом крайне низка.

Comment: @iluxa1810 я имею в виду шейдеры, вот например https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0dtbADIz3k или вот https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0j-LT1-9zME

Comment: Обязательно: базовые вещи вроде условий и циклов, ООП. Без этого даже начать не сможете. Если что, спросите тут, только, пожалуйста, не про статические переменные, про которые уже сто раз отвечали.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, должно быть уверенное владение языком.

В противном случае на выходе получаются инди-игры с графикой Doom 1, которые съедают ресурсы ПК из-за того, что кто-то не прочитал, как правильно работать со строкой, которую нужно изменять или ищет в большом списке значения не думая, что можно использовать какую-нибудь более оптимизированную структуру для поиска.

Answer (score 0):

Средние знания, возможно почти нулевые, читайте api scripting unity и старайтесь развивать логику придумывая решения проблем самостоятельно, всегда думайте, а можно сократить кол без потери функционала

Answer (score 0):

Самые простые, для движения игроков и платформ, еще перезапуск сцены(Легко в принципе), смерть от воды, в принципе почти нулевые. Ниже я привел список видеоуроков:

- [2d движение(англ)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwcT-Dch0bA)
- [2d движение(рус)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMGS1O646lw)
- [Смерть(англ)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmqVJ21V8Vw)
- Смерть на русском не нашел
- [Меню(рус)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVxzwa_Ftis)
- [Меню(англ)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8ac_qUXQY)

**Вроде все, советую английские туториалы(при знании языка)**